# How to upload file into Azure Blob Storage using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a console app that is written using C# on the top of Core.NET 2.2 framework.

I want to change my storage from local to Azure blob storage. I downloaded [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) to connect to my Azure account.

I have the following interface

```
public interface IStorage
{
    Task Create(Stream stram, string path);
}
```

I created the following interface as blob container factory

```
public interface IBlobContainerFactory
{
    CloudBlobContainer Get();
}
```

and here is my Azure implementation

```
public class AzureBlobStorage : IStorage
{
    private IBlobContainerFactory ContainerFactory

    public AzureBlobStorage(IBlobContainerFactory containerFactory)
    {
        ContainerFactory = containerFactory;
    }

    public async Task Create(Stream stream, string path)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = ContainerFactory.Get().GetBlockBlobReference(path);

        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

Then, in my `program.cs` file I tried the following

```
if (Configuration["Default:StorageType"].Equals("Azure", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    services.AddSingleton(opts => new AzureBlobOptions
    {
        ConnectionString = Configuration["Storages:Azure:ConnectionString"],
        DocumentContainer = Configuration["Storages:Azure:DocumentContainer"]
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IBlobContainerFactory, DefaultBlobContainerFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<IStorage, AzureBlobStorage>();
}
else
{
    services.AddScoped<IStorage, LocalStorage>();
}

Container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Resolve the storage from the IoC container
IStorage storage = Container.GetService<IStorage>();

// Read a local file
using (FileStream file = File.Open(@"C:\Screenshot_4.png", FileMode.Open))
{
    try
    {
        // write it to the storeage
        storage.Create(file, "test/1.png");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

However, when I use `AzureBlobStorage` nothing happens. The file does not get written to the storage and no exceptions are thrown!

How can I troubleshoot it? How can I correctly write the file to the storage?

Please note, when I change the configuration in `Default:StorageType` to `Local` the file is written locally as expected. But can't get it to write to the Azure blog.

Comment: Are you actually executing the Create method? It looks like you miss awaiting the result in your program.cs at "storage.Create(file, "test/1.png");"

Comment: @Random that actually did it! I was not aware that the code will not execute unless I await for it. I thought without awaiting it run in the background on a different thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet

```
public interface IStorage
{
    Task Create(Stream stream, string path);
}

public class AzureBlobStorage : IStorage
{
    public async Task Create(Stream stream, string path)
    {
        // Initialise client in a different place if you like
        string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
                    + "AccountName=[ACCOUNT]"
                    + ";AccountKey=[KEY]"
                    + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Make sure container is there
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
        await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Put your DI here
        var storage = new AzureBlobStorage();

        // Read a local file
        using (FileStream file = File.Open(@"C:\cartoon.PNG", FileMode.Open))
        {
            try
            {
                // Pattern to run an async code from a sync method
                storage.Create(file, "1.png").ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("Blob uploaded");
                    }
                }).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Omitted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look at this thread.
I added some answer to similar question

[ASP.NET Web API Azure Blob Storage Unstructured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498973/asp-net-web-api-azure-blob-storage-unstructured/54501050#54501050)

Comment: Compilation Error: 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'IsCompletedSuccessfully' and no accessible extension method 'IsCompletedSuccessfully' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)